# Is it possible to call another react native app on mobile in offline modus (locally)?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

The idea is to have a masterdata app with storing all the data and pushing the images etc, this app will not change that much is just a data store basically but also for offline scenario's.

And there is the other app which is the front end where we will do the deployment and create functions to other apps which are connected by local services (kind of offline microservice services architecture).

The questions is whether a react native app can do rest call locally to another react native app (basically locally). Was not able to find resources on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can open second app using deeplink.

And open corresponding screen on basis of deeplink and do the remaining stuff you want.

Comment: The question is not to open a 2nd app, to do a rest call locally to get data from 2nd app. I know that witha deeplink you can open a screen but need the data from the 2nd app.